# jQuery comboBox plugin - how can I get getSelectedIds from jQuery comboBox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

I am using two Jquery ComboBox object in single html. How can I set the selectedIds from each combo object into the corresponsing hidden input object . Here, the selected Ids from  ddlDepotMapping should be  stored in hfDepotMapping. Also the selected Ids from  ddlSalaryMapping should be  stored in hfSalaryMapping. But when the html page is being loaded , view-bag list item is not being selected on Jquery ComboBox Selected attribute

Here is the code

```
public IActionResult UserSetup
{
     List<GoUserDepartLink> mapping = _unitOfWork.UserDepartmentLink.GetAllDepartmentsByUserWithDepot(id);
     List<UserSalaryLocationLink> salaryMapping = _unitOfWork.User.GetUserSalaryLocations(id);
    user.SelectedDepotMapping = String.Join(",", mapping.Select(x => x.DepotNo + "." + x.DepartmentID).ToArray()) + "," + String.Join(",", mapping.Select(x => x.DepotNo).Distinct().ToArray());
user.SelectedSalaryMapping = String.Join(",", salaryMapping.Select(x => x.DepotNo + "." + x.DepartmentID).ToArray()) + "," + String.Join(",", salaryMapping.Select(x => x.DepotNo).Distinct().ToArray());
ViewBag.DepotDepartmentMapping = "[" + user.SelectedDepotMapping + "]";
ViewBag.DepotLocationMappingForSalary = "[" + user.SelectedSalaryMapping + "]";
}

public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()
{
        dynamic mappingList = new List<DepotMapModel>();
        mappingList = _unitOfWork.Department.GetDepotWithDepartment();
        return Json(mappingList);
 }


public dynamic GetDepotWithDepartment()
        {
            var list = goContext.goDepartmentWorkTime.
                GroupBy(d => new { d.DepotNo, d.Depot.DepotName })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                id = g.Key.DepotNo,
                title = g.Key.DepotName,
                subs = g.Select(dd => new
                {
                    id = dd.DepotNo + "." + dd.DepartmentID,
                    title = dd.Depot.DepotNo + "." + dd.Department.DepartmentName
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
            
            return list;
        }
```

```js
<script>
        FillDepartmentsMappings(@ViewBag.DepotDepartmentMapping);
        FillSalaryDepotsMappings(@ViewBag.DepotLocationMappingForSalary);
        //hfDepotMapping.Val(ddlDepotMapping.selectedIds) 
       // hfSalaryMapping.Val(ddlSalaryMapping.Selectedids)




function FillDepartmentsMappings(defaultSelected) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ddlDepotMapping').comboTree({
                source: data,
                isMultiple: true,
                cascadeSelect: true,
                collapse: true,
                selected: defaultSelected

            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });
    }

function FillSalaryDepotsMappings(defaultSelected) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                 $('#ddlSalaryMapping').comboTree({
                    source: data,
                    isMultiple: true,
                    cascadeSelect: true,
                    collapse: true,
                    selected: defaultSelected
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
            
        });
        
        
    }
</Script>
```

```html
<div class="controls col-sm-9">
       <input type="text" id="ddlDepotMapping" placeholder="Select" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfDepotMapping" asp-for="SelectedDepotMapping" />
</div>

<div class="controls col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="ddlSalaryMapping" placeholder="Select" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hfSalaryMapping" asp-for="SelectedSalaryMapping" />
  </div>
```

GetDepotWithDepartment() return the value in the format given below. I have to call that function in

```
{ id = 1, title = "1-DepotName1", subs = {System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType10<string, string>>} }
    subs: { id = "1.1", title = "1.Retail" }
        { id = "1.2", title = "1.Office" }
        { id = "1.3", title = "1.Warehouse" }
{ id = 2, title = "2-DepotName2", subs = {System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType10<string, string>>} }
        subs { id = "2.1", title = "2.Retail" }
        { id = "2.2", title = "2.Office" }
        { id = "2.3", title = "2.Warehouse" }
```

So , I have to call the function GetDepotWithDepartment from the   url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap" to get the data to populate in comboBox  in the place of your string  GetDepotDepartemntsForMap() function.

Comment: Rena, Many Thanks for the help. But my  request was different and sorry if my question is not enough to understand what  is I am looking for, How can I  set the selected Ids from the Javascript comboBox into the input type  hfSalaryMapping  like hfSalaryMapping.Val(The selected Ids from the javascript comboBox).

Comment: Hi @Alan Pauil, ok I know your requirement now. Just use `$("#hfDepotMapping").val(defaultSelected);` in success function. Check my updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the selected configuration is **type of array**.

You could set array in js like below:

```
selected: [defaultSelected]
```

Backend code:

```
ViewBag.DepotDepartmentMapping = 1;
ViewBag.DepotLocationMappingForSalary = 10;
```

The whole working demo:

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@model Test
<div class="controls col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" id="ddlDepotMapping" placeholder="Select" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hfDepotMapping" asp-for="SelectedDepotMapping" />
</div>

<div class="controls col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" id="ddlSalaryMapping" placeholder="Select" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hfSalaryMapping" asp-for="SelectedSalaryMapping" />
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/5.0.45/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree/comboTreePlugin.js"></script>
    <script>
        FillDepartmentsMappings(@ViewBag.DepotDepartmentMapping);
        FillSalaryDepotsMappings(@ViewBag.DepotLocationMappingForSalary);

    function FillDepartmentsMappings(defaultSelected) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ddlDepotMapping').comboTree({
                source: data,
                isMultiple: true,
                cascadeSelect: true,
                collapse: true,
                selected: [defaultSelected]    //change here...   
            });
            $("#hfDepotMapping").val(defaultSelected);      //add this...
        }
        //...
    });
    }

    function FillSalaryDepotsMappings(defaultSelected) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ddlSalaryMapping').comboTree({
                    source: data,
                    isMultiple: true,
                    cascadeSelect: true,
                    collapse: true,
                    selected: [defaultSelected]      //change here...
                });
                $("#hfSalaryMapping").val(defaultSelected);  //add this...
            }
            //......
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.DepotDepartmentMapping = 1;
    ViewBag.DepotLocationMappingForSalary =10;   

    return View();
}

public string GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()
{
    var SampleJSONData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");
    return SampleJSONData;
}
```

test.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Four Wheels",
        "subs": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "title": "Car"
            }, {
                "id": 11,
                "title": "Truck"
            }, {
                "id": 12,
                "title": "Transporter"
            }, {
                "id": 13,
        "title": "Dozer"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Two Wheels",
        "subs": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "title": "Cycle"
            }, {
                "id": 21,
                "title": "Motorbike"
            }, {
                "id": 22,
                "title": "Scooter"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Van"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Bus"
    }
]
```

Comment: Rena, But after changing  from defaultSelected into [defaultSelected] , the value is not passing from the  return Json(mappingList) from the function public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()

Comment: Hi @AlanPauil, The defaultSelected value comes from the ViewBag in your code provided. It is not related to the GetDepotDepartemntsForMap return data. What are you saying? Please share the correct code otherwise how can we help you?

Comment: Rena, Sorry  to hear that my code wasn't enough to give clear idea . Here I am using two function GetDepotDepartemntsForMap(),GetDepotWithDepartment() to get the list of Department mapped to the user and fill the comboBox when page is shown. You have provided string  GetDepotDepartemntsForMap() with string return in your code. But I have to use JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap() . Otherwise I have to change the code into Jsonresult into string . I dont know how can change JsonResult func into string func. I have added now two func in existing code. Many Thanks for kind mind to help us .

Comment: Hi @AlanPauil, You may misunderstand something.`GetDepotDepartemntsForMap` method is used to get the json result, no need to care how I get the result, just be sure your response is like what I shared in `test.json`.

Comment: And your first comment said `But after changing from defaultSelected into [defaultSelected] , the value is not passing from the return Json(mappingList) from the function public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()`. Again,The ViewBag data is not related to this GetDepotDepartemntsForMap method,ok? The VIewBag need to be set when main view(Index.cshtml in my project) first rendered. So you could see I set the value in my Index action.

Comment: What you need to do is to maintain `GetDepotDepartemntsForMap` and `GetDepotWithDepartment` method. Then using my `View(Index.cshtml)`. Be sure set the VIewBag before main page(Index.cshtml here) rendering. Finally, F12 in browser and choose `network` then click the request(`/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap` in your case) to check `the response`.It should be like my test.json.

Comment: Okay Rena , Many Thanks. I will check what is the way the result  is coming is like your test.json. I will check and will come back today

Comment: I have showed the data what is the way  the data is passed into the comboBox. Any help would be very appreciated. I have edited my original post

Comment: Rena, Please can you guide me how to bring my data  in the way you showed.  for example if the Depot model has, id =1 Depotname ='DepotName1',  Department model has Id=1 and DeparrtmentName ='Retail' then the  Jason  format would be Id:1 title= 'DepotName1',"subs" {id=1.1.title="1.Retail"}